# Finder Problem - USB drive opening in separate window for every folder

Tags: finder, hard-drive, macos, usb, windows

Whenever I connect my USB drive or insert a disc and view the contents every folder is opened in a separate window, how do I prevent this?

'Open folders in tabs instead of new windows'  in the Finder Preferences is ticked.

Im using a MacBook Pro Yosemite 10.10.1, I also experience the same issues when using my works iMac.

I should mention that the USB drive was formatted on my former computer which was Windows 7 and also the CDs that I have inserted have also been created on Windows.

Could this be the issue?

Best regards

Elbow

Answer (score 5):

The following trick worked for me.

- Focus the finder window from your external drive.
- Select **View** -> **Show Toolbar** option

Now, the finder window will not open in new windows. But, I have to do this every time I open from the external hard drive. I'm still looking for a solution to this.

Comment: Try, after making sure the window is just how you want it (including size, sort mode, etc), opening View Options (command-J) and selecting "Use as Defaults."